# Screen windows dies

Tags: gnu-screen

I am using screen with irssi, ssh to some servers. At the moment I have 4 windows "open" in my screen.

Two of those windows is "dead".
I can't write something in those, for example.

How do I "exit" a screen window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctrl-A K` will kill an unresponsive screen window.  That's assuming of course you've not remapped your screen command key from the default `ctrl-A`.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that some Windows users have a habit to press Ctrl-S from time to time (usually meaning to save something in other applications), but in putty+screen it blocks the window. To unblock such window one need to press Ctrl-Q. Check if it's not your case. Killing "dead window" is always my last try.

Comment: My problem is that I fumble S when I go for ctrl-A, and end up having to hit all sorts of wacky combinations of ctrl-q, ctrl-a q, ctrl-a ctrl-q before I get a response again.

Comment: @DerfK Another typo which can be tricky to figure out is typing ctrl-a C instead of ctrl-a c when trying to open a new window. The first visual feedback of either key combination is a blank window, but with ctrl-a c you get prompt shortly afterwards with ctrl-a C you don't.

Answer (score -1):

You can also delete the file /var/run/screen/[screen_number]

Comment: This answer is so incorrect that it is potentially harmful. You won't terminate any screen windows this way. You may however end up with an entire screen session which you can no longer attach to but what was running inside that screen session will remain running.